# web2py logic in orderby clause

Tags: sql-order-by, web2py

I am performing a db query in web2py using the DAL, and I want to use the equivalent of an SQL orderby clause like this:

```
... ORDER BY table1.col1 = 'my text' DESC, table2.col2 DESC;
```

But I can't seem to work out the syntax for providing logic in the orderby clause. E.g. the following is not valid syntax

```
db().select(..., orderby =~ (db.table1.col1=='my text')| db.table2.col2))
```

I could provide the orderby clause as an SQL string, but then I would need to ensure that 'my text' is correctly SQL-escaped (the actual string is passed in by the user). So if there is no way to put logic in the web2py DAL `select(orderby=...)` clause, then is there a way to escape SQL strings for use in the orderby clause as an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
orderby = [
    (db.table1.col1 == user_input, 'DESC'),
    (db.table2.col2, 'ASC')
]

db().select(..., orderby=', '.join('%s %s' % level for level in orderby))
```

With this method, you must manually specify 'DESC' and 'ASC' rather than using the `~` operator to indicate a descending order. If desired, you could write a function to take your original syntax and convert it to something like the above.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful and quick as always. Your solution is just what I needed, only the python syntax needs to be `",".join('%s %s' % level for level in orderby)`.